# Does the spectrum of Sol's emission change as it ages?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, sun, spectroscopy

A follow-up to my earlier question [How would one navigate interstellar space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31924/5265) that just occurred to me; albeit on a different tack.

Sol is probably in a state of continuous flux. The change of state is probably over large timescales as compared to the life-span of the average human. If one were to compare a spectrograph of Sol over a span of, say, 10 million years, would the graph be significantly & predictably different?

Comment: @CrazyBuddy: Would that I had dmckee, or ronmaimon, or johnrennie's expertise to come up with an answer ... *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

Each & every element has its own characteristic emission and absorption spectra (which we all know). As the star traverses its main sequence stage - the hydrogen atoms are actually getting used up to form helium atoms. As it enters the red giant phase, helium starts to fuse by the triple-alpha process.

The [Hertzsprung-Russel diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertzsprung-Russell_diagram) gives the relationship between temperature and luminosity (Blue, yellow, red, etc.). As we take [Wien's displacement law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_displacement_law) also into account, we could conclude that the spectra (emission or absorption) of the sol varies accordingly with its temperature. Now, the sun is at some 5000 K surface temperature, which gradually decreases to something around 3000 K. And hence, the spectral shift from yellow towards red. But, that may take about 3 or 4 billion years.

---

Oh.. You asked for 10 million years. In that case too, the answer remains the same. It's on its own way, hanging its spectrum because its getting *old..*!